Crystal Field Theory, in a tetrahedral complex, why would $d_{z^2}$ and $d_{x^2-y^2}$ be degenerated ? In terms of counting of repulsion
In Crystal Field Theory, for a tetrahedral (metallic) complex, shouldn't the $d_{z^2}$ and the $d_{x^2 - y^2}$ have different energies, since the repulsion between one lobe and ligands happens $2$ times in the $d_{z^2}$ orbital and $4$ times in the $d_{x^2 - y^2}$ ?
If we were to note down the amount of overall repulsions, we should have normally twice more repulsions for the $d_{x^2 - y^2}$ than for the $d_{z^2}$ orbital.
I don't understand why they would have to be degenerated despite of the reason I'm invoking above.
Or does the donut of $d_{z^2}$ have something to do with this ?
PS: Here are my drawings, the pinkish violet dots represent the ligands. The blue dots represent the extremities of the lobes of the orbital. First drawing is for $d_{z^2}$, second one is for $d_{x^2-y^2}$. As you can see, the repulsion is the same for each of the $6$ lobes, my concern is: isn't the $d_{x^2-y^2}$ further destabilized because of the twice-as-more repulsion experienced by the its lobes?


PS2: Actually I haven't really taken into account the donut of $d_{z^2}$ in my first drawing. Have to say I don't know how to handled it. Especially I don't know how can the $d_{z^2}$ with its donut be equal in energy to the $d_{x^2-y^2}$.

I don't really understand what you are asking without the image. And yes it's probably something with the donut…

I've added a rapidly drawn image (sorry first one rendered pretty well but the second one is really ugly). I can redraw it if you wish.

Imagine there are two tetrahedra. One is the actual one, and the other is inverted through the center to complete a cube. The $d_{x^2-y^2}$ and $d_{z^2}$ orbitals go through the face centers and tend to stay away from the ligands, while the other $d$ orbitals go through the cube edges and thus approach the ligands somewhat more closely.
With only one of the tetrahedra, the same ordering occurs, the only difference being that with just half as many ligands as the full cube the energy differences are cut in half. This is one reason tetrahedral complexes show little orbital splitting in both crystal-field theory and the more advanced ligand-field theory.
